# Selenium Grid, Protractor - Can you restrict capability to be executed to a certain node only

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-grid

does anyone know of a way to restrict the execution to certain capability's specs to a certain Selenium grid only? I.e (nodeIp configuration) :

```
{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'platform': 'ANY',
  'version': 'ANY',
  'nodeIP': '192.168.128.13',
  'chromeOptions': {
     'args': [

        '--start-maximized',
        'incognito',
        '--disable-extensions',
     ],
     'prefs': {
        'download': {
           'prompt_for_download': false,
           'default_directory': downloadFolderPath
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean restrict execution on the specific selenium node?

Comment: Exactly. But not all the tests, only the tests that are associated with a certain capability.

Answer (score 0):

One of possibly solutions:
add one more browser with custom version as example `'version': 'specialTest'`. You will have 2 chromes, one with version "ANY" and one with version "specialTest". In this way you need use driver with version setted to "specialTest" in your case.

```
{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'platform': 'ANY',
  'version': 'ANY',
  'nodeIP': '192.168.128.13',
  'chromeOptions': {
     'args': [

        '--start-maximized',
        'incognito',
        '--disable-extensions',
     ],
     'prefs': {
        'download': {
           'prompt_for_download': false,
           'default_directory': downloadFolderPath
        }
     }
  }
},
{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'platform': 'ANY',
  'version': 'specialTest',
  'nodeIP': '192.168.128.13',
  'chromeOptions': {
     'args': [

        '--start-maximized',
        'incognito',
        '--disable-extensions',
     ],
     'prefs': {
        'download': {
           'prompt_for_download': false,
           'default_directory': downloadFolderPath
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to run test where you need to download some files?

Comment: No, I was hoping there was a way to tell protractor/ selenium grid / jasmine (not sure whom) to execute one capability per node (whichever one) and at a time, so that tests continue to be distributed automatically, but no two tests from different capabilities can be executed at the same time on the same node. The reason for this is because we need to execute tests with different users, passed as parameters to the respective capability, but we don't want two users running tests on the same node in parallel (in our configuration or application instances are also Selenium grid nodes)

Comment: @Lucy you can allow only 1 session for the node by adding `'maxSession': 1`

Comment: As in adding it to the capabilities?

Comment: If you add `maxSession': 1` to the node configuration and register it to hub, only 1 test will be running at a time in the node.